# How to set more than one limit on for loop : javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with javascript arrays, here i am using for loop to get the top three results.(no .length limit)

Attempting to have something like

```
for(let a=0;a<usss.length || a<3;a++)
```

Simple

```
var users = ['s','g','h','i'];
for(let a=0;a<3;a++){//dont want to use a < users.length
   console.log(users[a]);
}
```

problem

```
var users2 = ['s','g'];
for(let a=0;a<3;a++){
  console.log(users2[a]);
}
```

The way around,

```
var users2 = ['s','g'];
for(let a=0;a<users2.length;a++){
 if(a<3){
  console.log(users2[a]);
 }
}
```

**Real Question**

> How can i avoid using extra if() condition in my last stated code?

I am sorry if its very basic question, i just stuck on it.
Any help or information will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work :

```js
var users = ['s','g','h','i'];

var users2 = ['s','g'];

for(let a=0;(a<3 && a<users.length) ;a++){
   console.log(users[a]);
}

for(let a=0;(a<3 && a<users2.length);a++){
  console.log(users2[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be no way without using an `if` somewhere as you have to check the length of the value.

```js
var users = ['s','g','h','i'];

// define the length value outside
var length = users.length >= 3 ? 3 : users.length;

for(let a=0; a < length; a++){
   console.log(users[a]);
}

var users2 = ['s','g'];
for(let a=0; a < length; a++){
   console.log(users[a]);
}


// you can define it inside the for loop but it's not so nice for reading
for(let a=0; a < (users.length >= 3 ? 3 : users.length); a++){
   console.log(users[a]);
}
```

Maybe the nicest would be to create a function and pass the `3` as a maxLength parameter

```js
var logMax = function(users, maxLength, info) {
  let length = users.length >= maxLength ? maxLength : users.length;
  for(let a=0; a < length; a++){
    console.log(info, ' => ' + users[a]);
  }
}

var users = ['s','g','h','i'];
logMax(users, 3, 'first');

logMax(['s','g'], 3, 'second');
```

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan I don't see how this answer `avoid using extra if() condition` as you asked in your "real" question ... it's basically the same thing you did in your workaround in a function

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan `users.length >= maxLength ? maxLength : users.length;` This is a ternary `if` condition ;) you did not avoid anything

Comment: yes you are right, i agree that this isn't avoiding 'if' rather its one-liner. i didn't paid attention. thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1):

You could use also use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Note: Check browser compatibility and/or use polyfill

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].some((el, idx) => {
  console.log(el);
  return ++idx === 4; /* <-- return top 4 */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the lesser of 2 values as the limit, you can use `Math.min()`.

```
let users2 = ['s','g'];

for (let a = 0; a < Math.min(users2, 3); a++) {
    console.log(users2[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, I think you just need to go through the length of the array.

```
 var users2 = ['s','g'];
for(let a=0;a<users2.length;a++){
  console.log(users2[a]);
}
```